# How to make a datatable group by column values of a column?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could somebody tell me how can I apply a filter on a datatable columns values
like below is that column values of datatable
now in my grid header I have a dropdown list that has got a unique values for the above columns like sd, tf, er.
Now I want datatable to make table values grouped by dropdown list selected value.

So my misery is I am unable to group the values of a datatable by column values.

The grouped values must be on the top of that table all below.

```
  protected void ddlSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
        string ddlValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
        customerDetailGrid.Sort(ddlValue, SortDirection.Ascending);
    }
    protected void customerDetailGrid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PopulateCustomer");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dtSortTable = DB.ExecuteDataTableCommand(cmd);//customerDetailGrid.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dtSortTable != null)
        {
            DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);
            dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);
            customerDetailGrid.DataSource = dvSortedView;
            customerDetailGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }



    private static string getSortDirectionString(SortDirection sortDireciton)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;
        if (sortDireciton == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code, what have you tried?

Comment: It's terrible to have the sql statements in your code behind.

Comment: But the aove code sort on column basis, while i want it to sort by some of column valus..

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have similar issue, I want to group by columns which names are passed as string array